# How can I get JMeter results in xls and csv formats simultaneously after running one test?

Tags: maven, jenkins, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I'm using Jenkins + Maven + JMeter (3.1) + Report Dashboard + Performance Plugin (2.0). Linux, non-GUI mode.
I need to get two files after performing one test - in xls and csv formats.
The solution that I found and now use is getting xls results via Maven and getting the csv file through the [Simple Data Writer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xrax.png).
In 'Simple Data Writer', the folder and destination file are hard-coded.
Such a decision seems to me very rude.
Is there a beautiful solution to this problem through Maven?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any path hard-coded in the Simple Data Writer, maybe this is you, who are putting an immutable value there?

If you need a configurable way of setting Simple Data Writer output path you can use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like `${__P(path,)}` in its "Filename" input:

[image: Simple Data Writer JMeter Property]

This `path` variable in its turn can be passed via [propertiesSystem](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Modifying-Properties#adding-additional-properties-to-propertiessystem) or [propertiesUser](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Modifying-Properties#adding-additional-properties-to-propertiesuser) sections of your `pom.xml` file. Again, the values don't have to be hard-coded, you can use a [Maven Property](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties) as a value and set this via `-D` command-line argument.

References:

- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Modifying Properties](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Modifying-Properties)